# When service appeal to from check TGT valid?

Tags: cas

I started to study **CAS** and ran into a not entirely clear moment. If you log in to the service through the **CAS**, the service will be issued with a **TGT** with a certain **timetolife**. But if after authorization, for example, turn off the **CAS** or delete the **TGT** issued to it on **CAS** server, the service will continue working without interrupting the user session. The question, at what points does the service check the state of the **TGT** on the **CAS** server in order to understand that the **TGT** still exists and no expired?

thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no need to logout the service when TGT is expired or deleted.

Because

- TGT represents logged-in user information in CAS.
- When the service needs to login to CAS, it uses TGT and the user doesn't need to explicitly enter username and password on the login screen.
- If there is no TGT, then the user must be explicitly login to CAS.

In a nutshell, TGT prevents again and again user logins for a certain time. **TGT and services have nothing to do directly, and the services don't need to check TGT validity.**

Check the flow diagram https://apereo.github.io/cas/6.2.x/protocol/CAS-Protocol.html#web-flow-diagram